# Connect media files and ads

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm able to list ads:

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v5/ad_group_ad

```
select
    ad_group_ad.ad.id,
    ad_group_ad.ad.name
from
    ad_group_ad
```

And media files:

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v5/media_file

```
select
    media_file.id,
    media_file.media_bundle.url
from
    media_file
```

But I'm unable to connect the two. I tried many things:

This gives: `The following field may not be used in SELECT clause: 'ad_group_ad.ad.image_ad.media_file'.`

```
select
    ad_group_ad.ad.id,
    ad_group_ad.ad.image_ad.media_file
from
    ad_group_ad
```

Then this gives: `Unrecognized field in the query: 'ad_group_ad.ad.image_ad.media_file.id'.`

```
select
    ad_group_ad.ad.id,
    ad_group_ad.ad.image_ad.media_file.id
from
    ad_group_ad
```

And tried to remove all the prefixes from `ad_group_ad.ad.image_ad.media_file.id` without any success. I also tried the `ad_group_ad_asset_view`, but that returned empty response for all the customers I tried, and it also doesn't have a media file ID.

Is there a solution?